# Move installation to external drive

Tags: boot

I want to move an existing internal Ubuntu installation to an external drive.

I've put what was my internal HDD into and external case and set my bios to recognise booting from USB. The result is I just get a blank screen from the start.

I've tested the booting from USB with a seperate Ubuntu installation USB and it recognises it and allows me to test or install as it should.

I'm guessing I need to change the boot folder on the now external drive, but the searching I've done I can't find how to do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43158/how-do-i-transfer-an-installation-from-internal-to-external-usb-hdd

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't seem to work.  After trying several different approaches the best I've managed is to get a grub error message.  Apparently it's a bug with Ubuntu.  As an interim solution have used Lili Usb Creator for a live version with a 4GB persistent state.  Although this persistent state just sits on top on the version so far it gives me all the control I need including installing.